# How can I force the name property on the input fields in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

I'm trying to switch off autofill Chrome built-in function in my Angular 9 app. I found the Chrome attach the autofill suggestions to the name of the input field.

I have this Angular 9 HTML code:

```html
<input
  [class]="inputClass"
  [(ngModel)]="model[field]"
  [id]="field"
  [name]="field + '_' + random"
  [placeholder]="getPlaceholder()"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [type]="type"
  [autocomplete]="random"
  (keyup)="validateField()">
```

And I get this in the generated HTML code if I run the app:

```html
<input
  _ngcontent-cbv-c111=""
  class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
  ng-reflect-model=""
  id="name"
  ng-reflect-name="name_6xuz5"
  placeholder="My placeholder"
  type="text"
  autocomplete="6xuz5">
```

Now here isn't a `name` property on `input` tag. And that's because I use this syntax: `[name]="..."`. If I use the `name="..."` syntax then the name property will be presented.

How can I force the `name` property on the `input` fields and still use the `[name]="..."` syntax to give a calculated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[name]` tells Angular that this is a *property* binding (like an input), but you want to set an HTML *attribute*. For this you can instead use

```
<input [attr.name]="field + '_' + random" …>
```

which tells Angular that you want to set it as an attribute.

Alternatively, you can also use

```
<input name="{{ field + '_' + random }}" …>
```

but arguably that doesn't look as pretty.

---

This is a bit confusing in Angular, and there are plans to at least improve the documentation, [see this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35867#issuecomment-595148254).